# HTTPD service not starting properly

Tags: apache

I am facing an issue wherein after doing the patching activity on one of my linux server, the httpd service is not starting properly.

```
[root@sessxuwpd00001 srp1]# ps -ef | grep -i httpd
root     28866     1  0 09:16 ?        00:00:00 /opt/app/srp1/bin/httpd -d /opt/app/srp1 -k start
nobody   28869 28866  0 09:16 ?        00:00:00 /opt/app/srp1/bin/httpd -d /opt/app/srp1 -k start
nobody   29180 28866  0 09:24 ?        00:00:00 [httpd] <defunct>
root     29182 26542  0 09:24 pts/1    00:00:00 grep -i httpd
```

Although during the service restart I do not get any error and the status of apachectl says service is running but in the logs I get the below error message,

> /opt/app/srp1/bin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /opt/app/srp1/bin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_global_mutex_lockfile

I have checked and recreated the symbolic link for the aprutil as well,
libaprutil-1.so.0 -> libaprutil-1.so.0.5.4

Not sure, what is causing this issue. I have searched on the Google and tried different solutions but to no success.

Comment: - Check if "apr apr-devel apr-util apr-util-devel apr-util-ldap" packages are installed on your machine. And verify if the link is correct by checking the output of "ldd /opt/app/srp1/bin/httpd". Let me know if this helps.